# file 'lib' not found when installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, installation

something like this:

```
gem install rails
Fetching: activesupport-3.0.10.gem (100%)
Fetching: builder-2.1.2.gem (100%)
WARNING: builder-2.1.2 has an invalid nil value for @cert_chain
Fetching: i18n-0.5.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: activemodel-3.0.10.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-1.2.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-test-0.5.7.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-mount-0.6.14.gem (100%)
Fetching: tzinfo-0.3.29.gem (100%)
Fetching: abstract-1.0.0.gem (100%)
WARNING: abstract-1.0.0 has an invalid nil value for @cert_chain
Fetching: erubis-2.6.6.gem (100%)
Fetching: actionpack-3.0.10.gem (100%)
Fetching: arel-2.0.10.gem (100%)
Fetching: activerecord-3.0.10.gem (100%)
Fetching: activeresource-3.0.10.gem (100%)
Fetching: mime-types-1.16.gem (100%)
Fetching: polyglot-0.3.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: treetop-1.4.10.gem (100%)
Fetching: mail-2.2.19.gem (100%)
Fetching: actionmailer-3.0.10.gem (100%)
Fetching: thor-0.14.6.gem (100%)
Fetching: railties-3.0.10.gem (100%)
Fetching: bundler-1.0.18.gem (100%)
Fetching: rails-3.0.10.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-3.0.10
Successfully installed builder-2.1.2
Successfully installed i18n-0.5.0
Successfully installed activemodel-3.0.10
Successfully installed rack-1.2.3
Successfully installed rack-test-0.5.7
Successfully installed rack-mount-0.6.14
Successfully installed tzinfo-0.3.29
Successfully installed abstract-1.0.0
Successfully installed erubis-2.6.6
Successfully installed actionpack-3.0.10
Successfully installed arel-2.0.10
Successfully installed activerecord-3.0.10
Successfully installed activeresource-3.0.10
Successfully installed mime-types-1.16
Successfully installed polyglot-0.3.2
Successfully installed treetop-1.4.10
Successfully installed mail-2.2.19
Successfully installed actionmailer-3.0.10
Successfully installed thor-0.14.6
Successfully installed railties-3.0.10
Successfully installed bundler-1.0.18
Successfully installed rails-3.0.10
23 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-3.0.10...
Installing ri documentation for builder-2.1.2...
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for README, skipping
Installing ri documentation for i18n-0.5.0...
Installing ri documentation for activemodel-3.0.10...
Installing ri documentation for rack-1.2.3...
Installing ri documentation for rack-test-0.5.7...
Installing ri documentation for rack-mount-0.6.14...
Installing ri documentation for tzinfo-0.3.29...
Installing ri documentation for abstract-1.0.0...
Installing ri documentation for erubis-2.6.6...
Installing ri documentation for actionpack-3.0.10...
Installing ri documentation for arel-2.0.10...
Installing ri documentation for activerecord-3.0.10...
Installing ri documentation for activeresource-3.0.10...
Installing ri documentation for mime-types-1.16...
Installing ri documentation for polyglot-0.3.2...
Installing ri documentation for treetop-1.4.10...
Installing ri documentation for mail-2.2.19...
Installing ri documentation for actionmailer-3.0.10...
Installing ri documentation for thor-0.14.6...
Installing ri documentation for railties-3.0.10...
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.0.18...
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.10...
file 'lib' not found
Installing RDoc documentation for activesupport-3.0.10...
Installing RDoc documentation for builder-2.1.2...
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for README, skipping
Installing RDoc documentation for i18n-0.5.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for activemodel-3.0.10...
Installing RDoc documentation for rack-1.2.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for rack-test-0.5.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for rack-mount-0.6.14...
Installing RDoc documentation for tzinfo-0.3.29...
Installing RDoc documentation for abstract-1.0.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for erubis-2.6.6...
Installing RDoc documentation for actionpack-3.0.10...
Installing RDoc documentation for arel-2.0.10...
Installing RDoc documentation for activerecord-3.0.10...
Installing RDoc documentation for activeresource-3.0.10...
Installing RDoc documentation for mime-types-1.16...
Installing RDoc documentation for polyglot-0.3.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for treetop-1.4.10...
Installing RDoc documentation for mail-2.2.19...
Installing RDoc documentation for actionmailer-3.0.10...
Installing RDoc documentation for thor-0.14.6...
Installing RDoc documentation for railties-3.0.10...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.0.18...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.0.10...
file 'lib' not found
```

and if i run `rake db:migrate`

it says:

```
  ............
    rake aborted!

stack level too deep
```

Comment: Which version of which ruby are you using?

Comment: ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this :

```
sudo gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

and if you want to install RDoc use :

```
sudo gem install rdoc-data
sudo rdoc-data --install
sudo gem rdoc --all --overwrite
```

if that doesnt work try this :

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev build-essential
```

Comment: @MounaCheikhna I know this post is really old but I have just come across this problem.  Do I need to uninstall first and then try re-installing this way, or can I type in the above without uninstalling what I've installed?

Answer (score 5):

Note, the following also seems to work on Windows 7. (omit the "sudo")

```
gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Answer (score 5):

I got similar with `gem install rails` (Ubuntu 12.04, with RVM)

```
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.13...
file 'lib' not found
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.13...
file 'lib' not found
```

installing RDoc and then reinstalling rails solved the problem for me. So:

```
gem install rdoc
gem install rails
```

Answer (score 2):

This is still happening on rails-3.2.3.

What appears to work is to install rdoc first.  So, with a freshly installed ruby, do:

gem install rdoc
gem install rails

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are some issues with ree and ruby 1.8.*. If you have rvm try use ruby 1.9.2 or any 1.9.*

then

gem install rails  will work

Comment: it didn't work for me. I have ruby 1.9.2p312 installed via rvm.

Comment: sorry after which i them ran "gem install rails --no-rdoc --no-ri ". Thats what seem to have worked for me